# Get Reports On Ads Using Google Ads Api

Tags: ads, google-ads-api

I am trying to get the reports for **campaigns** and **ads** performance.
So far i have gotten the campaign performance reports, but i am unable to to get ads performance reports.

I have seen the google ads api and and their examples in client library. But i am unable to understand how to get ad reports.

I making a function that will fetch the reports for me via google ads api.

Google Ads Api: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/fields/ad_group_ad#ad_group_adadexpanded_text_addescription2

Google Ads Api Github: https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php/

```
public function getAdsPerformance($customerId)
{
    // Customer ID which i am using ---> 2942416690
    try {
        // Creates a query that retrieves all campaigns.
        $query = 'SELECT ad_group_ad.ad.expanded_text_ad.description2 FROM ad_group_ad';

        // Issues a search request by specifying page size.
        $response = $this->googleAdsServiceClient->search($customerId, $query, ['pageSize' => $this->page_size]);

        // Iterates over all rows in all pages and prints the requested field values for
        // the campaign in each row.
        foreach ($response->iterateAllElements() as $googleAdsRow) {
            $adGroup = $googleAdsRow->getAdGroupAd();
            // $customer = $googleAdsRow->getCustomer();
            // $metrics = $googleAdsRow->getMetrics();

            /** @var GoogleAdsRow $googleAdsRow */
            $result = [
                'ad' => $adGroup->getResourceName()->getValue(),
            ];
            print "<pre>";
            print_r($result);
            print "</pre>";
        }
    } catch (GoogleAdsException $googleAdsException) {
        printf(
            "Request with ID '%s' has failed.%sGoogle Ads failure details:%s",
            $googleAdsException->getRequestId(),
            PHP_EOL,
            PHP_EOL
        );
        foreach ($googleAdsException->getGoogleAdsFailure()->getErrors() as $error) {
            $error = [
                'code' => $error->getErrorCode()->getErrorCode(),
                'status' => $error->getStatus(),
                'message' => $error->getMessage()
            ];
            printf(json_encode($error));
        }
    } catch (ApiException $apiException) {
        $error = [
            'code' => $apiException->getCode(),
            'status' => $apiException->getStatus(),
            'message' => $apiException->getBasicMessage()
        ];
        printf(json_encode($error));
    }

}
```

I am trying to get this type of simple values from api in array

```
Array
(
   [campaign] => some test campaign
   [currency] => PLN
   [clicks] => 100
   [impressions] => 300
   [cost] => 250.08
   [avg_position] => 1.07
   [avg_cpc] => 0.8
   [conversions] => 0
   [cost/conv] => 0
   [conv_rate] => 0
   [ctr] => 0.9
   [avg_cpm] => 2.5
   [interaction_rate] => 0.1
   [interactions] => 52
)
```

Any idea about how can i get the ad reports from the api, Anybody done it? I can't seem to figure out seeing documentation and the client library.

Comment: Don't forget about RSAs. They're a little trickier and the assets come back in a dict that you need to parse yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i did it with some research. There are two types of ads.

**1. Expanded Text Ads**

**2. Call only Ads**

I checked what was the type of my ad running, and it was 'Expanded Text Ads'. And then picked the field **ad_group_ad.ad.expanded_text_ad.headline_part1** from the api documentation from here:

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/fields/ad_group_ad#ad_group_adadexpanded_text_adheadline_part1

this is complete function:

```
public function getAdsPerformance($customerId)
{
    try {
        $query =
            'SELECT ad_group_ad.ad.expanded_text_ad.headline_part1 '
            . 'FROM ad_group_ad '
            . 'WHERE ad_group_ad.ad.type = EXPANDED_TEXT_AD';

        $response = $this->googleAdsServiceClient->search($customerId, $query, ['pageSize' => $this->page_size]);

        foreach ($response->iterateAllElements() as $googleAdsRow) {
            $ad = $googleAdsRow->getAdGroupAd()->getAd();
            $result = [
                'headline part 1' => $ad->getExpandedTextAd()->getHeadlinePart1()->getValue(),
            ];
            print "<pre>";
            print_r($result);
            print "</pre>";
        }
    } catch (GoogleAdsException $googleAdsException) {
        printf(
            "Request with ID '%s' has failed.%sGoogle Ads failure details:%s",
            $googleAdsException->getRequestId(),
            PHP_EOL,
            PHP_EOL
        );
        foreach ($googleAdsException->getGoogleAdsFailure()->getErrors() as $error) {
            $error = [
                'code' => $error->getErrorCode()->getErrorCode(),
                'status' => $error->getStatus(),
                'message' => $error->getMessage()
            ];
            //                return $error;
            printf(json_encode($error));
        }
    } catch (ApiException $apiException) {
        $error = [
            'code' => $apiException->getCode(),
            'status' => $apiException->getStatus(),
            'message' => $apiException->getBasicMessage()
        ];
        printf(json_encode($error));
    }
}
```

And i got the field result:

```
Array
(
   [headline part 1] => Small Business System
)
```